# How to not show open with window for download file in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bittorrent

I have Firefox version 35.0.1 (the most recent) up to this date.

I have set to use mTorrent as the default application to open when I try to download a torrent file but everytime the window with "open with  and save to dialog opens. I already set my application I want the files to open with but firefox asks me everytime to click "OK".

Expected behavior is: Click on torrent file -> automatically open inside application I have set as default beforehand.
Behavior now: Click on torrent file -> dialog asking me to open with or save to opens, mtorrent.exe is pre-selected inside the open with dropdown.

I tested with chrome and using chrome the expected behavior happens.

What do I have to change inside firefox?

Answer (score 1):

In **preferences -> applications** search for **torrent** and change the action to whatever you like.. In your case probably: "use mtorrent(default)"

Comment: like I said it is already set to use torrent as default. this is also shown in the dropdown menu inside the prompt window. nevertheless the prompt still pops up. if you find time please test it with chrome and firefox. in chrome you wont see a window poping up asking you where to save or to open with which application. in firefox it will.